# Open virtual keyboard when selecting an input on Windows 10 touchscreen

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, windows-10, virtual-keyboard

I am creating a web application targeting Windows 10 touchscreen.

The problem is when the user touches a text input, she has to click on the virtual keyboard icon on the task bar to open the virtual keyboard.

> Is there a way to automatically open the Windows virtual keyboard when a user touches an input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. It is a setting in Windows 10.

> In Settings -> Tablet mode
>
> `Make Windows more touch-friendly when using your device as a tablet.`
>
> Turn on